# Do natives say "I'll be happy to be proven otherwise"?

Tags: subjunctives

> While **I'll be happy to be proven otherwise**, it should be pretty clear by now that no such thing exists.

Do native speakers say **"I'll be happy to be proven otherwise"** ?

Comment: No. Mostly we don't use ***proven*** anyway, but much more likely would be *I'd be happy to be **proved wrong**.*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: Where I come from, we do say **proven**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Strange. I'd always thought most modern instances of ***proven*** for ***proved*** were dialectal Scottish hangovers, but [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happy+to+be+proven%2Chappy+to+be+proved&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chappy%20to%20be%20proven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chappy%20to%20be%20proved%3B%2Cc0) suggests the usage has increasingly been gaining traction in AmE (the "Scottish" factor isn't even enough to be reflected in the BrE corpus chart for this one! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A native speaker might very well *say* something like that, or even write it in a casual situation.

I think if someone says, "I'll be happy to be proven otherwise," they are mixing up

> A) "I'll be happy to be proven wrong,"

and

> B) "I'll be happy if *it* proves to be otherwise."

Both of those expressions convey pretty much the same idea. But to really be right, you ought to stick with either A) or B). The combination, "... happy to be proven otherwise," doesn't make a lot of sense. While it sort of sounds familiar at first, if you think about it, it's not really right. It would mean that the *person himself* was proved to be "otherwise," (whatever that might mean.)

Comment: Lorel, I am upvoting your answer. I must have been writing my answer when you posted yours. Although the two answers are very similar, you deserve an upvite for being succinct and prompt.

Comment: You can imagine situations where *I"ll be happy to be proven otherwise* kind of makes sense. Consider a new Hogwarts student who hasn't been sorted: *"I think I'm probably a natural Slytherin. While I'll be happy to be proven otherwise ..."* But you're right in that almost certainly, *"I'll be happy to be proven otherwise"* is a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

First, **proved** is somewhat more common than **proven** according Ngram, but **proven** is certainly acceptable. (This may be a regional difference. Certainly where I live **proven** is very common.)

Second,

> While I'll be happy to be proven otherwise...

is the kind of error that happens frequently in speech. People start by thinking one thing and then think of an alternative. What comes out is a mix that is wrong, but native speakers will figure it out unconsciously. People who do not take the time to write carefully will then write this sort of thing in more formal situations. So what thoughts were scrambled?

> Although I'll be happy if it is proved/proven otherwise, ...

where "it" is whatever proposition is being discussed, is being confused with

> Although I'll be happy to be proved/proven wrong, ...

A person cannot be demonstrated to be otherwise; it is a meaningless idea. But people can be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good in terms of the overall question. (As a Canadian, perhaps with more US influence in this case, I'm more likely to say *proven* than *proved*.) But I wanted to mention something that hasn't been brought up yet.

I think it's generally more common for people to say ***I'd*** **be happy** than it is for them to say ***I'll*** **be happy**, particularly if what's under discussion is only a *possibility* rather than a certainty.

Let's say I've bought a lottery ticket:

> ✔ I'd be happy to win.
>   ✘ I'll be happy to win.

Normally, people would not use *will* in this case. Instead, they would use *would*.

In the case of your example sentence, which wording is used would be based on the person's assumption of likelihood of being proven wrong. If it's probable that they are wrong, then they'd use *I'll*; otherwise, I think they would be more likely to use *I'd*.

Since this sentence concludes with "it should be pretty clear by now that no such thing exists," the speaker would normally choose ***I'd***.

[Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27ll%20be%20happy%20to%2CI%27d%20be%20happy%20to%2C%20I%20will%20be%20happy%20to%2C%20I%20would%20be%20happy%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27ll%20be%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27d%20be%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20will%20be%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20would%20be%20happy%20to%3B%2Cc0) suggests this too:

[image: I'd be happy to]